# Which charset for converting a String to Hex?

Tags: java, string, hex

I use this code to convert a String to a Hex value:

```java
public static String toHex(String arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

The code seems to work fine but I don't understand the comment

```
/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/
```

What am I supposed to put there?

Comment: Tried with `"UTF-8"` ?

Comment: If you leave it empty, it uses your system's default charset. You can change it if you want

Comment: @JornVernee don't leave it empty. Your platform's default charset may be EBCDIC or another charset that is not the same as ASCII for the first 127 characters.

Comment: Using `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` will allow any Unicode String to be decoded fully. Besides that `getBytes()` will give different results on different computers as it uses the platform encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code seems to work fine but I don't understand the comment
>   /YOUR_CHARSET?/ ? Am I supposed to put there?

The method [`String#getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) converts a `String` into an `array of bytes` by encoding it using **the  platform's default charset**.  Calling `String#getBytes()` is risky as it makes your code dependent on the platform which could lead to decoding issues later if you change of platform, that is why it is highly encouraged to use `String#getBytes(charset)` instead in order to clearly specify the target charset this way it will work properly whatever the platform used **assuming** that the charset specified can cover properly all the characters of the `String` to encode. Indeed if you have for example accentuated characters in your `String` and you use a non matching charset like for example `ASCII` you will get decoding issues later.

Answer (score 0):

You get to decide, but whatever you decide, you have to tell the receiver or you have failed at communication. Or, if you are following a specification, consult that specification.

Also, you probably want to use an encoding for a character set that covers your data, otherwise some characters will be replaced with question marks. Given that the character set for Java's `String` is Unicode, the UTF-8 encoding for Unicode is an obvious choice.